# Trying to get Devise New Registration as the Home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

so I have been looking for this answer and the devise docs kind of have an answer to customizing sign in and sign out but its not quite what I was looking for and I have tried it only to fail.  Basically, I would like to incorporate the sign up form fields for a new user in my app on the home page or root_path.

I tried copying and pasting, which didnt work cause the resources are needed, I tried changing the routes to the route path root :to => "devise/registrations#new" and that didnt work, so then I looked up the customization of sign in and out and changed the scope to get "/", => "devise/registrations#new" which also didn't work.

Is there an easier way to do this?  Or am I just missing something along the way?

Comment: Maybe try `devise/users#new` replace users with the name of your resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
end
```

Make sure that you have "/" matched to something, though, and obviously run `rake routes`.

EDIT:  You can also run `rails g devise:views` which will give you all of the devise views in your `views` folder.  Then in your home page, you can `render 'devise/reg_form'` (or whatever the registration view is called).

Comment: I tried this and got, Could not find devise mapping for path "/". Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example: devise_scope :user do match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end. Even tho I did wrap the route inside the scope block like you said.  The rake routes show '/' going to the right controller and action.  I think I am just getting confused with the whole devise system. Is there an easier way to just move the form to the home#index view?

Comment: This is definitely on the right track.  I forgot about just rendering them.  The problem with this is just like copy and pasting, the devise form is looking for a resource.  Is it complicated to change the resource or can I just use user, since it uses the user model.

Comment: Thanks again, I found the answer here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app.  I just needed to provide helper methods for the users controller.

Answer (score 0):

Might not work for all cases but you can do something like:

`root to: redirect('/users/password/new')`